# Configuring nginx for multiple websites on one vps

Tags: nginx

I've read a lot of articles about this today, but I can't get what am I doing wrong.
I'm trying to use one vps with nginx for placing two websites (site1.com, site2.com) on it together.

Here is my nginx.conf

```
user www-data;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;
    tcp_nodelay        on;

    gzip  on;
    gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.(?!.*SV1)";

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

conf.d directory is empty, and there is my configs in sites-enabled directory:

```
server {
        listen   80 default;
        root /home/site1/www;

        access_log  /home/site1/logs/nginx.access.log;

        server_name site1.com;

        location / {
                index index.php index.html index.htm;
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
                fastcgi_index  index.php;
                fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                include        fastcgi_params;
        }
}
```

and

```
server {
        listen   80;
        root /home/site2/www;

        access_log  /home/site2/logs/nginx.access.log;

        server_name site2.com;

        location / {
                index index.php index.html index.htm;
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
                fastcgi_index  index.php;
                fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                include        fastcgi_params;
        }
}
```

Of course /home/site1/www and /home/site2/www both contains files of website.

Now if I trying to open site1.com, here is interesting:

I've get: Can't open site1.com:81 error

What am I doing wrong? Why there is this 81 port added to URL?

Comment: Any proxy setup in your browser?

Comment: nope, no proxy in my browser

Comment: The problem is somewhere else than in the nginx configuration you have shown.

Answer (score 1):

I think just change the *listen  80* to  *listen  81*  in the server of the site1.com